# Ajax response always returns 2 after first call

Tags: javascript, ajax, response

I'm trying to use Ajax to get an updated num from my DB.
The main function is :

```
function checkInvitations() {
    if (username ="-1") {
        username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    }
    req.open('GET', 'check_num_of_invitations.php?username='+username);
    req.onreadystatechange = handleNumOfInvitationsResponse;
    req.send(null);
}
```

The function is called from the HTML file ...
The called function (`handleNumOfInvitationsResponse`) :

```
function handleNumOfInvitationsResponse() {
if(req.readyState == 4) {
    // update div in HTML
} else {
    // update div in HTML
}
setTimeout(function(){checkInvitations();}, 5000);
```

}

Notice the recursive call to `checkInvitations`.

On the first try, the response returns 4 and everything works, from there on it returns with 2.
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code which gives the response?

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)...why just 4??

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Internet Explorer 9 and I solved it by appending a timestamp to query string:

```
 var url = 'check_num_of_invitations.php?username='+username+'&timestamp='+Date.now();
 req.open('GET', url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why would it help ? BTW, it was tested by Chrome.

Comment: It could be because of cache, but chrome is ok. Doesn't help :(